# C#-WebRequest in a Windows Service

Tags: windows, service, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I'm currently developing a Windows Service to download some emails in the background. For easy testing, the core of this service can be run in a standalone application, too.
There's no problem while downloading the mails (service and standalone) but I'm not able to get a WebRequest when running the service (everything's find in the standalone app).
I know, Windows Services are limited by the local system account - but is there a way to work with (Http-)WebRequest without changing the service-user manually.

Thanks in advance,
Bert

Comment: Do you get an error/exception. If so can you add the stack, message etc?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try disabling proxy ?

I had the same issue and setting proxy to null fixed the Timeouts.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
request.Proxy = null; // bypass autodetect proxy
```

When you run as standalone application, your account proxy settings will be used.
When runned as Service, Local Service Account is used and default proxy settings are used.

You can also try to add a breakpoint and lookup the proxy field
with your debugger. This will gives you a better view of the "running Service context"

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```